# Natural numbers that are square sums of four different nonzero integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, sums-of-squares

It's known that any natural number can be expressed as a sum of four squares.
Conjecture:

> A natural number can be written as a square sum of four different
>   nonzero integers if and only if it not is a potency of two and not is
>   a member of the set:
>
> {3,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,31,33,34,35,36,38,40,41,43,44,47,48,49,52,53,56,59,68,73,76,80,83,88,96,104,112,128,144,160,192,208,224,304,320,384,416,448,640,768,832,896,1280,1536,1664,1792,2560,3072,3328,3584,5120,6144,6656,7168,10240,12288,13312,14336,20480,24576,26624,28672}.

So far tested up to $2^{16}$.

Comment: sum of 4 perfect squares is a more proper phrasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OEIS entry for the positive integers that are not the sum of four distinct non-zero perfect squares](http://oeis.org/A004441) says that your conjecture is wrong. Specifically, their [list of the first $1000$ numbers](http://oeis.org/A004441/b004441.txt) shows a lot of numbers that are not powers of $2$ even after your $28\,672$. Here are the numbers from that list between $2^{15}$ and $2^{16}$ in the sequence:
$$
\begin{array}{}
31744\\
32768\\
33792\\
34816\\
36864\\
37888\\
38912\\
40960\\
43008\\
44032\\
45056\\
48128\\
49152\\
53248\\
56320\\
57344\\
59392\\
61440
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Erroneous programming.